# expo | only changes on state while call arrow-function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, arrow-functions

i have a problem with following function;

```
const handleSave = (task, description, priorityState, taskID) => {
  changeLabel(task, taskID);
  changeDescription(description, taskID);
  changePriority(priorityState, taskID);
  navigation.goBack();
};
```

the problem is thats only change the last used function:

if i'll change the Label and the Description its only save the Description for example. <
i call the function while clicking a Button (TouchableOpacity)

```
<Button
  title={language.edit.save}
  color={theme.secondary}
  onPress={() => {
    handleSave(task, description, priorityState, taskID);
  }}
/>
```

any advise?

what did i try?
delay the functions:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const handleSave = (task, description, priorityState, taskID) => {
  changeLabel(task, taskID);
  sleep(10); 
  changeDescription(description, taskID);
  sleep(10); ...
};
```

i would like to thank any kind of help <3

[full code here.](https://www.github.com/andy-bergner/simple-todo)

Comment: As a side note: `sleep(10)` returns a Promise. If you don't `await` it, it won't wait for it to finish

Comment: Did you try to put it all the state that changes together in a single state object (e.g. only one `useState()` instead of three)? I remember this helped me some time ago, but don't know why

Comment: I assume `changeLabel`/Description/Priority are custom functions, and there is a high probability the issue is caused by their inner working, so without their code, it is almost impossible to provide relevant help. Please make sure to share a [mcve].

Comment: @ghybs i added a github link. context/task/Index.js there are all the functions

Comment: @A_A thx for the Information i'll try it as soon i'm back from School tomorrow. (eu time | 16:00uhr/4:00pm)

Comment: Next time make sure to provide a _minimal_ code. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @ghybs i cant rn  im not on my pc I'll do it tomorrow.. i'm dont ask many question here. rn on my phone so i just added github link. on my other comment i said i'll do it tommorrow after scholl

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 custom functions `changeLabel`, `changeDescription` and `changePriority` all try to update the *same* `tasks` state:

[Repo source](https://github.com/andy-bergner/Simple-Todo/blob/2a3a07c6781ea0ff05daec2eccef37e9384a3936/src/context/task/index.js#L33-L61)

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

const changePriority = (color, taskID) => {
  const task = tasks.map(/* etc. */);
  setTasks(task);
};

const changeDescription = (description, taskID) => {
  const task = tasks.map(/* etc. */);
  setTasks(task);
};

const changeLabel = (value, taskID) => {
  const task = tasks.map((/* etc. */);
  setTasks(task);
};
```

When you successively call these functions, each one reads the *current* `tasks` state, which *has not been updated yet* by the previous call to `setTasks` SetStateAction. See also [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately/54069332#54069332)

You can easily solve this by using the [functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of the SetStateAction:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

In your case, change your 3 functions to get the previous state as a parameter:

```js
const changePriority = (color, taskID) => {
  setTasks(
    // Use previous tasks received as argument
    // instead of directly tasks which may be
    // an old value.
    (previousTasks) => previousTasks.map(/* etc. */)
  );
};

// Same for the other 2 functions.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @ghybs worked. I appreciate your work  Thx

i changed the function from:

```
const markTask = (taskID) => {
  const task = tasks.map((item) => {
    if (item.id == taskID) {
      return { ...item, completed: true };
    }
    return item;
  });
  setTasks(task);
};
```

to this:

```
const changeLabel = (value, taskID) => {
  setTasks((previousTasks) =>
    previousTasks.map((item) => {
      if (item.id == taskID) {
        return { ...item, label: value };
      }
      return item;
    })
  );
};
```

[snack with the issue](https://snack.expo.dev/@andy-gerome/change-state-issue)